# Is there a way to filter an array by values of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I am building a react app and I am trying to filter an array based on the values of another array.

This is my code:

```js
const filter_ids = [
  "Y5Xtg3T2V4aYHilhU0c6", 
  "DeVpCBd98yXksB5NM4tw"
]

{datas && datas.filter(data => data.id  === filter_ids)
    .map(data =>{
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>data</li>
      </ul>
    )
  })}
```

I would like to have it such that if an object from the **datas** array has an ID that matches any one of the values on the **filter_ids**, it returns that object. When I do it like this, it doesnt work.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Array#includes

```js
const filter_ids = [
  "Y5Xtg3T2V4aYHilhU0c6", 
  "DeVpCBd98yXksB5NM4tw"
]

{datas && datas.filter(data =>filter_ids.includes(data.id))
    .map(data =>{
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>data</li>
      </ul>
    )
  })}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{datas && datas.filter(data => filter_ids.includes(data.id))...
```